# SQL query for finding countries in the world with 3 times bigger population than all of the countries at the same continent

Tags: sql

I have a table which name is 'world'. That table has columns in this order: name, continent, area, population and gdp. The query i want to write is for the next problem:
Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of their neighbours (in the same continent). Give the countries and continents.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT 
    name, continent 
FROM 
    world as x
WHERE
    x.population/3 > ALL (SELECT population 
                          FROM world as y 
                          WHERE x.continent = y.continent)
```

But it doesn't work as it is supposed to. What can be the possible problem?

Comment: Your query does not exclude the original country from the comparison.

Comment: ***WHAT*** RDBMS is this for?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. What is the possible suggestion?
@marc_s it's online from the site: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/

Comment: Add condition in sub-query, where x.name <> y.name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I find the use of the `any`, `all`, and `some` keywords to be a bit hard to follow.  I find it easier to interpret such a query when it uses `min()` and `max()` explicitly:

```
SELECT w.name, w.continent 
FROM world w
WHERE w.population > (SELECT 3 * MAX(w2.population) 
                      FROM world w2
                      WHERE w2.continent = w.continent AND
                            w2.name <> w.name
                     );
```

In addition, the use of `min()` and `max()` in the subquery make it behave more intuitively when there are `NULL` values that the subquery might return.

Note that I have included table aliases for each for the table, and *used* them to qualify column names.

Comment: I think you'll want to wrap that subquery in a `COALESCE()` for cases such as Australia - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40982

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT x.name, x.continent
  FROM world x
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM world y
                     WHERE y.continent = x.continent
                       AND y.name <> x.name
                       AND y.population >= x.population/3 );
```

In other words, get all countries where there is not another country on the same continent with even 1/3 the population. The advantage this has over using an aggregate with a subquery is that it will return values for continents with only one country. **[See SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40981) (WHERE EXISTS) vs [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40982) (MAX)**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, continent FROM world x
  WHERE population>ALL (SELECT 3*population FROM world y
                         WHERE x.continent=y.continent
                         AND x.name<>y.name   
                         AND population>0)
```

Comment: The question was: *What can be the possible problem?* So I think it would be good to say what was wrong and why your query is better.